# Use Segmented Control with TabBarController without TabBar (on bottom) disappears

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to use Segmented Control to choice between contact form and contact details in the contact ViewController in my app. The contact ViewController is managed by the TabBarController. But when switching by using the Segmented Control the TabBar on the bottom disappears.

I uploaded a sample project here: [SegmentedControlTest](http://www.filedropper.com/segmentedcontrolltest)

Is there a simple way to solve that issue?

Regards,
David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the current structure you can:

1. Embed ContactFormVC in NavigationController (editor -> embed in -> NavigationController) and on the NavigationController property uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar"
2. On both ContactFormVC and ContactDetailsVC set its "presentation" property (under "Transition Style") to "Current Context"; Your storyboard will look like this
   [image]

You should change your transition to push and pop instead of both "show" otherwise you'll keep adding on the navigation stack. It's easy to do via code, I can't find how to do this via storyboard. I also recommend changing the structure for your view controllers as suggested by previous answer.

The way I encourage you to do is to use [single view controller with multiple container views](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/).

*Connecting .swift code to storyboard. Make sure the class name on custom class section is the same as the class' name. In this case it's "ViewController.swift"
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already found this tutorial myself and am just trying it.

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to connect anything to ViewController.swift. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: It might be because the class is not connected to the scene / VC on storyboard. I'll add a screenshot on my answer

Comment: Seems to work now, also with TabBarController. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That might be the issue then. On new projects the first scene and class are connected. But you should keep that in mind when adding new VC on your own

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood now what you mean. The problem was I copy/pasted the code from the website. That changed `class ViewController: UIViewController` to `class ViewControllerSwift: UIViewController`.

Comment: Do I have to create new .swift files for these "external" Views to customize the elements inside?

Comment: I made it and it's working: `class ContactDetails: UIViewController`. But is `UIViewController ` the right?

Answer (score 0):

I download your sample project.
As your segue's type is `show`,and you want didn't want to disappear tabbar,I guess you only want to exchange the `form view` with `detail view`.Not show another viewcontroller.

You can solve it by create detail view not detail view controller.

An alternative solution is that you can change `UITabBarController`'s    `viewControllers`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. Your idea sounds reasonable. I would be better just to change the view, not the whole ViewController. I also tried it but didn't work. How to do that?

Comment: you can own two views by viewcontroller.And use `addSubview:` & `removeFromSuperview` to update views  when your valuechanged event is received.

Comment: I never heard about this before. Do you have a link or so for me how to do that?

Comment: @David, you can check my answer I just posted. On the very bottom I added a link to a tutorial page which should help you with what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much @DicksonLeonard.